# xsl transformation based on value from input

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I need my xml output, however the output xml is based on a condition from the value from the input.
The output xml is not a transformation of input xml.
The xml is in another variable which is accessed by document function. Here i used the xml within *xslt* itself using document function.

The *xml* accessed by document function has id attributes which have values in ascending order. The input is a number(say from the input xml) and that number should be compared with the id attribute of the document accessed xml starting from the top choice element. If at any occurence the corresponding value (id attribute + 15) is greater than the input number, the particular choice element and the preceding choice elements should be ignored from the output *xml*.

Example if the input number is 100, output should be the below as the first element that met the condition is for the id value "90". As 90 +15 is greater than 100.

```
<menu>
     <choice id="95">C</choice>
     <choice id="100">C</choice>
   </menu>
```

My input xml is say

```
<a>100</a>
```

My xslt which outputs everything

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:elements>
   <menu>
     <choice id="20">ABC</choice>
     <choice id="23">B</choice>
     <choice id="30">C</choice>
     <choice id="37">C</choice>
     <choice id="45">C</choice>
     <choice id="50">C</choice>
     <choice id="90">C</choice>
     <choice id="95">C</choice>
     <choice id="100">C</choice>
   </menu>
 </my:elements>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/my:elements/*"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach.  Think of it as pseudocode.  You'll have to plug in the details.

```
<!-- Find the id of the first choice that over the limit.  --> 
<xsl:variable name="firstChoiceOverLimitID" select="generate-id(document('')/*/my:elements//choice[number(@id) + 15 &gt; 100][1])"/> 
  
<xsl:template match="/">
  <!-- Output everything after the first choice over the limit.  -->
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/my:elements//choice[generate-id(.) = $firstChoiceOverLimitID]/following-sibling::choice"/>
</xsl:template>
```